# 'Duplicate accepted' banner suggests there are multiple originals

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, notification-bar, plurals

When you 'accept' a duplicate target for your question, the question will be closed and a banner will be shown:

> Great! We'll associate your post with **these questions** so future visitors can easily find the answer.

(emphasis mine)

However, in most cases, the [original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256420/295232) is just a single question. Can the wording be changed to reflect this?

[image]

Comment: I wonder how it behaves with multiple duplicate targets, and in theory a post could be associated with more than one...

Comment: _"in most cases..."_ Are there cases where _the OP_ can choose multiple dup-targets?